# XSLT 2.0 / XPATH - choose-when testing node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

In XPATH under XSLT 2.0, I am unclear as to why an `xsl:choose/xsl:when @test` isn't working.

When I run this template testing for the element `tei:del[@rend='expunctus']`, the test DOES NOT return the result:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:del[@rend='expunctus'] | 
    tei:gap | 
    tei:sic | 
    tei:supplied[@reason='added'] | 
    tei:surplus[@reason='repeated' or @reason='surplus']  |
    tei:unclear">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tei:del[@rend='expunctus']">
            [<xsl:text>EXPUNCTUS</xsl:text>]
        </xsl:when>
</xsl:template>
```

When I run this template with just the attribute `@rend='expunctus'` as the test, the test DOES return the result:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:del[@rend='expunctus'] | 
    tei:gap | 
    tei:sic | 
    tei:supplied[@reason='added'] | 
    tei:surplus[@reason='repeated' or @reason='surplus']  |
    tei:unclear">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@rend='expunctus'">
            [<xsl:text>EXPUNCTUS</xsl:text>]
        </xsl:when>
</xsl:template>
```

Is this because of the current node already selected?

I prefer to test against the element, not just the attribute, to eliminate possible ambiguity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because of the current node selected.

Your template matches `tei:del[@rend='expunctus']` (amongst other things), so when you do `<xsl:when test="tei:del[@rend='expunctus']">` this is relative to the node you have matched, so it is looking for another `tei:del` as a child node of the current node.

What you probably need to do is this...

```
<xsl:when test="self::tei:del[@rend='expunctus']">
```

Alternatively, consider using separate templates for each possible node and putting any shared code in a named template.

Comment: This worked perfect, and because this `xsl:choose` block treats the same subject (editorial footnotes) it's preferable to try to keep it together rather than break it into 20-odd templates. But you can see that I've run into further trouble with this (using your suggestion of `intersect` and variable) just posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891964/xslt-2-0-xpath-intersect