# XSLT 2.0 XPATH intersect

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Under XSLT 2.0, [I am trying to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739824/xslt-converting-style-down-from-3-0-to-2-0-variable-reference-error) `intersect` to use an xsl:variable in an XPATH expression. Files at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiK6/1 (problem below at lines 175-192 in the xslt).

I declare a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="app-sources" select="tei:del[@rend='expunctus'] | 
    tei:gap | 
    tei:sic | 
    tei:supplied[@reason='added'] | 
    tei:surplus[@reason='repeated' or @reason='surplus']  |
    tei:unclear"></xsl:variable>
```

And I am using that variable here with `intersect`, and it does not output the expected result:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[. intersect $app-sources]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::tei:del[@rend='expunctus']">
            [<xsl:text>EXPUNCTUS</xsl:text>]<xsl:apply-templates/><sup> 
           <xsl:number count="*[. intersect $app-sources]" format="a" level="any"/></sup>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

Expected result in HTML`[EXPUNCTUS]quondam<sup>b</sup> quandam` (around line 465 in the HTML output).

But if I substitute `*[. intersect $app-sources]` with the original XPATH, it works fine:

```
 <xsl:template match="tei:del[@rend='expunctus'] | 
    tei:gap | 
    tei:sic | 
    tei:supplied[@reason='added'] | 
    tei:surplus[@reason='repeated' or @reason='surplus']  |
    tei:unclear">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::tei:del[@rend='expunctus']">
            [<xsl:text>EXPUNCTUS</xsl:text>]<xsl:apply-templates/><sup> 
           <xsl:number count="tei:del[@rend='expunctus'] | 
                                 tei:gap | 
                                 tei:sic | 
                                 tei:supplied[@reason='added'] | 
                                 tei:surplus[@reason='repeated' or @reason='surplus']  |
                                 tei:unclear" format="a" level="any"/></sup>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

Curiously, `intersect` works perfectly fine in `<xsl:template match="*[. intersect $footnote-sources]" mode="build_footnotes">` just below the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a global variable with

```
<xsl:variable name="app-sources" select="tei:del[@rend='expunctus'] | 
    tei:gap | 
    tei:sic | 
    tei:supplied[@reason='added'] | 
    tei:surplus[@reason='repeated' or @reason='surplus']  |
    tei:unclear"></xsl:variable>
```

all your paths like `tei:del` are used to select with the primary input document node as the context node and your primary input document has a `TEI` root element but certainly no `del` or `gap` or any of the other elements as child nodes of the document node. So you will need to make sure you use paths like `//tei:del` or `//dei:gap` to select any descendants elements of the used name of the primary input document.

Of course as you are also using temporary documents created by modes it might be that for that variable you don't want to select descendants of the primary input document but rather ones from a temporary result you have in another variable, so in that case you would need to use e.g. `$foo//tei:gap` in your path expressions selecting the nodes bound to the `app-sources` variable.